# Linux command GREP - Exact value with space

Tags: linux, grep

```
$ cat file.txt | head -n10
icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=50.0 ms
icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=51.9 ms
icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=50.9 ms
icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=49.9 ms
```

```
$ cat file.txt | grep -v 'time=5 . ms' | head -n 5
icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=50.0 ms
icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=51.9 ms
icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=50.9 ms
icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=49.9 ms
```

I want it like this with all lines with "time=5X.XXms" ​​excluded:

```
$ cat file.txt | grep -v "time=5 . ms" | head -n 5
icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=49.9 ms
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use `[0-9]` for `X`, which would give the following regular expression:

```
time=5[0-9].[0-9][0-9] ms
```

So you get following command:

```
cat file.txt | grep -v "time=5[0-9].[0-9][0-9] ms" | head -n 5
```

Comment: should be just one `[0-9]` after the `.` character.. can also use `grep -m5 -v 'time=5[0-9].[0-9] ms' file.txt` to do it in one command instead of three

Comment: Perfect! I just added the space:

cat file.txt | grep -v 'time=5[0-9].[0-9] \ms'

Thanks

Comment: Note that `.` will match any character unless quoted.

Comment: The [`cat` is useless](/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat) and the `head` can be avoided with `grep -m 5`